# Primefaces Charts with Two Y Axis

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, charts

Is it possible to have double Y axis chart using Primefaces

Can anyone please share the example for the same ?

This is my chart:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3a00fp2p79p658/graphic.png

I need to apply the second Y axis.

Comment: Does displaying different kind of data on the same chart makes sense ? Can it be user-comprehensible ? Displaying two stacked charts (one under the other) could be a better solution as their width and X axis are the same.

Comment: Hi Stephane. The combined chart is about some kind of data. In bar chart, I show the values (minutes) and the line chart, the percent is shown. See this other example.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3a00fp2p79p658/graphic.png

Comment: The answer is:  this.cfg.series[1].yaxis = 'y2axis'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's an old article for which the referred data on dropbox does not exist anymore. All relevant parts of the answer or question should make integral part by including and/or quoting the original text. You can add proper sourcing if necessary.

Comment: dead dropbox link

Answer (score -2):

Check out the following white paper:
http://downloads.nevron.com/company/WhitePaperAxisDocking.pdf

it shows how to create a chart with multiple y axes.

Comment: Nevron's solution works for .NET. The OP is asking a question specific to PrimeFaces.

Comment: That's not even Java.